Difference between Wirtinger derivative and complex differential
Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. What exactly is the difference between the Wirtinger derivative $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$ and the complex derivative $f'$. To my understanding, in both cases you just "take the derivative" as if $z$ were a normal variable, as in $z^2\to 2z$. Am I misunderstanding the definitions? If not then how are they different?

They agree for complex differentiable functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives under "Relation for complex differentiation"

Being holomorphic means the second wertinger derivative is zero $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$ by Cauchy Riemann equations.
